# C:\....bin\spark-shell 'cmd' is not recognised as....'

Tags: apache-spark

I am very new to Spark and need your help.I want to run spark 2.0.2 (Hadoop 2.7)on Windows 8. I have defined system variables and values as:

```
Java_Home    C:\Progra~1\Spark Ecosystem\JDK\jdk1.8.0_111.
Hadoop_Home  C:\Program Files\Spark ecosystem\winutils.
Spark_Home   C:\Program Files\Spark ecosystem\Spark\bin.
Path          %Java_Home%\bin; %Hadoop_Home%; %Spark_Home%;
```

I have installed Eclipse, its exe file is working. Java -version is working ok but spark-shell command is not recognized...

Answer (score 0):

You must *not* override the path. Just append to it.

`cmd` is the Windows "shell", located in `%WINDIR%\system32`. You need to leave it in the path (it like if you removed the path to `/bin` on linux: not much would work after that)

for instance do this (append original value of `PATH` in your startup script):

```
set PATH=%Java_Home%\bin;%Hadoop_Home%;%Spark_Home%;%PATH%
```

minimalist version:

```
set PATH=%WINDIR%\system32;%Java_Home%\bin;%Hadoop_Home%;%Spark_Home%
```

Comment: Thanks Jean-François Fabre. I have set PATH as you suggested (adding %PATH%), but problem still stays the same.

Comment: Thanks Jean-François Fabre! after providing 'WINDIR\...', there is a little progress but still???.
Now when I run spark-shell and get error stating "The system cannot find the path specified. Failed to find Spark jars directory. You need to build Spark before running this program".